# CakePHP $this->Auth->login() return false

Tags: cakephp, authentication, frameworks

I created a User with the hash provided by the Cake .. But when I go to log in, says 'Invalid username or password'. But it's all right.

The `$this->Auth->login();` always returns false...

Crontroller

```
class MastersController extends AppController{

public function login(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        debug($this->Auth->login());
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } 
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
   }
}
public function logout(){
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}}
```

AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array('Session', 'Cookie', 'Auth');
    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->loadModel('Master');

        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Master';
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
        // Action da tela de login
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
                'masters' => false,
                'controller' => 'masters',
                'action' => 'login'
        );

        // Action da tela após o login (com sucesso)
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
                'masters' => true,
                'controller' => 'masters',
                'action' => 'index'
        );

        // Action para redirecionamento após o logout
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(
                'masters' => false,
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'login'
        );
        $this->Auth->authorize = array('controller');
        if (!isset($this->params['masters']) || !$this->params['masters'])
            $this->Auth->allow('*','login');

        $this->Auth->loginError = __('Usuário e/ou senha incorreto(s)', true);
        $this->Auth->authError = __('Você precisa fazer login para acessar esta página', true);
    }

    public function isAuthorized($masters){
        return TRUE;
    }}
```

VIEW login.ctp

```
 echo 'Formulário de login';
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Session->flash();
echo $this->Form->create('Master', array('controller'=>'masters','action'=>'login'));
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Entrar');
```

Model

```
class Master extends AppModel{
public $name = 'Master';
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Usuario requerido.'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Senha requerida.'
        )
    )
);

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I don't know why it is giving this error .. This all seems ok!
I changed one letter of Security.salt, as he asked ..
Help me :)
I need it for work

Comment: The password probably does not match or your session is not configured propertly. Is the result of `debug(AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']))` the same as the password value in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
debug($this->Auth->login());
if ($this->Auth->login()) {}
```

is a bad idea.
the first will log you in,
the second call will then - of course - return false (since you are already logged in).

If you really need to test this way, halt the code:

```
debug($this->Auth->login()); die();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what fixed it for me was changing $this->alias to User, so beforeSave() now looks like

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```